"hf-internal-testing/tiny-stable-diffusion-pipe" from Diffusers seems broken
I am trying to run the small tiny-stable-diffusion-pipe model from HuggingFace but it looks like it's broken and won't sample properly.
import os
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("hf-internal- 
testing/tiny-stable-diffusion-pipe", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")
prompt = "a picture of a rabbit"
images = pipe(prompt, num_images_per_prompt=1).images

gives
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (12545) must match the size of tensor b (226) at non-singleton dimension 1
Try it yourself in this google colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AE5uA68myGvyzEi-vm4w806EN9rdjzq4?usp=sharing
I was expecting the model to sample when using
images = pipe(prompt, num_images_per_prompt=1).images
